# Sass fails to @extend selectors created with the parent selector

Tags: sass, extend

I need to create CSS output done with SCSS and placeholder in a certain way

This is the output that I want

```
.myclass {
  color: silver;
}
.myclass-gold {
  color: gold;
}
```

---

When I try this with a [SCSS placeholder](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors) like this

```
%placeholder {
  color: silver;
  #{&}-gold {
    color: gold;
  }
}

.myclass {
  @extend %placeholder !optional;
}
```

I only get this result

```
.myclass {
  color: silver;
}
```

The gold part is dropped altogether.

---

I need a placeholder, because I use many selectors like `a.myclass`, `input.myclass` etc and don't want the exploded @export from these

If I do not use a placeholder but a random selector—and take some extry bytes—the output is not right, either

```
ae739ab7 {
  color: silver;
  #{&}-gold {
    color: gold;
  }
}

.myclass {
  @extend ae739ab7 !optional;
}
```

yields

```
ae739ab7, .myclass {
  color: silver;
}
ae739ab7 ae739ab7-gold, .myclass ae739ab7-gold {
  color: gold;
}
```

---

and

```
ae739ab7 {
  color: silver;
  &-gold {
    color: gold;
  }
}

.myclass {
  @extend ae739ab7 !optional;
}
```

gives me

```
ae739ab7, .myclass {
  color: silver;
}
ae739ab7-gold {
  color: gold;
}
```

What's missing here is always the selector `.myclass-gold`

**Is this possible somehow with some magic trick?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extends only work on exact matches.  When you write this:

```
%placeholder {
  color: silver;
  #{&}-gold {
    color: gold;
  }
}
```

What you've really created is this:

```
%placeholder {
  color: silver;
}

%placeholder %placeholder-gold {
  color: gold;
}
```

So when you write this:

```
.myclass {
  @extend %placeholder !optional;
}
```

It will only extend the `%placeholder` selector and not `%placeholder-gold` selector.  To get the behavior you're looking for, you have to extend each placeholder selector individually:

```
%placeholder {
  color: silver;
  @at-root #{&}-gold {
    color: gold;
  }
}

@mixin placeholder {
    & {
        @extend %placeholder;
        @at-root #{&}-gold {
            @extend %placeholder-gold;
        }
    }
}

.myclass {
  @include placeholder;
}
```

Output:

```
.myclass {
  color: silver;
}
.myclass-gold {
  color: gold;
}
```

Comment: I never thought of using extend inside a mixin.